# Epson thermal printer port forwarding

Tags: router, port-forwarding, printing, network-printer

I am installing an Epson TM T70 thermal printer with an ethernet interface at our office and trying to forward two ports in the router to make it accessible publicly and be able to print from the web.

I forwarded two ports to the printer's 80 and 9100 ports, but I can't make it accesible. The 80 is for the web interface of the printer and the 9100 is the one used listening print jobs.

I think that the problem isn't at the router, because I can forward a port to a local web server without any problem.

I hope that I had explained myself specific enought to understand the problem, otherwise I can provide any detailed informating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That....is something you really don't want to do. A printer that is open to the internet will be found within hours and exploited, have thousands of print jobs passed to it, or both.

Stated plainly, printers are not designed to be freely accessible on public networks.

Instead of implementing your plan, stand up a VPN service that users can connect to, and **then** print to your printer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not an expert at this kind of network stuff... I can't stand up a VPN, so my solution was develop a small API (and install it in the local network) from which I can control access to printing jobs and send them to the printer.